# Find largest common subsequence

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have the following code, which does not work correctly for some reason that I am trying to figure out:

```
public static int score(String gene1, String gene2){
    char[] a=new char[gene1.length()];
    char[] b=new char[gene2.length()];
    a=gene1.toCharArray();
    b=gene2.toCharArray();
    return score(a, b, 0,0);
}

private static int score(char[] a, char[] b, int i, int j){
    if(a[i]=='\0' || b[j]=='\0')
        return 0;
    else if (a[i]==b[j])
        return 1+score(a, b, i+1, j+1);
    else 
        return max(score(a, b,i+1, j),score(a, b, i, j+1));
}

private static int max (int a, int b){
    if (a<b) return b;
    else return a;
}
```

Here is where it fails:

```
assertEquals(2, GeneAnalysis.score("ACGT","AC"));
```

I get an IndexOutofBoundsError

Any ideas? Also, when offering help, please do not change method parameters. They are supposed to be the way they are.

Comment: is this homework ? Interesting. you have asked 45 questions and given 0 answers.

Comment: Show us the input, actual output and expected output when asking questions like this, please.

Comment: You have the line, `char[] a=new char[gene1.length()];`.  Then you have the line, `a=gene1.toCharArray();`.  Thus your initializer is useless -- you should change the fisrt line to `char[] a = gene1.toCharArray();`.  (And same deal with `b`)

Comment: Why are you doing char[] a=new char[gene1.length()]; and then doing a=gene1.toCharArray(); ? Won't fix your problem, but will remove some silliness in your code :-)

Comment: I posted this on the answer, but for anyone: Ok now that I have working code, I realized I got pretty lucky. I have small idea of how it works, but not a full one. I tried tracing it on paper, but it gets really messy. Whats a good way of trying to understand how this is working?

Comment: @Bill: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @Roger why--it's one of the most useful tags on the site?  Who came up with this policy and why?

Comment: @Bill: There's a lot of discussion on the linked post.  Why do you think it's a useful tag?

Comment: @Roger because it reminds the answerer at what level the answer should be targeted.  It's inappropriate to answer a homework question with a full-code answer, Snippets and suggestions are helpful, full-code is harmful--No other tag adds as much actual context and gives the answerer more information.  The comment you linked to makes a big jump by adding homework to the list of "subjective" tags, the post it referred to didn't mention it at all except in a comment that called it out as an assumption.  Looks like someone took it on themselves to remove the most useful tag in the system.

Comment: @Bill: Mark tagged it [homework] because he saw something about how the question was asked; is it unreasonable to think answerers can see this too?  So you're really using [homework] for "this is a basic/beginner question", not "this was assigned by my teacher"?  Don't you see a problem with that?  Why do you think the [beginner] tag was removed?  (And [beginner] is explicitly mentioned in the blog post, which didn't have an exhaustive list.)  Isn't using tags, which are supposed to be about the *content* of the question, to *tell other people how to answer* different from every other tag?

Comment: @Roger, no--anyone who used it as "Beginner" is wrong.  It is used by the poster to indicate it was assigned as homework or added if the question is very basic and is written in such a way that it absolutely must have been homework. If there is a question, you ask the poster to voluntarily tag it as homework.  Jeff specifically said that this kind of tag is an edge case that doesn't need regulation, but other-jeff seemed to have taken it upon himself to subvert the advice into a policy. Pity. (Of course, I also think searching for "Easy" in cooking would be about the most useful tag possible)

Comment: @Bill: How is "asked by a beginner" different from "question is very basic"?  Many of the times people add it to a question they seem to mean "beginner" — and the blog post mentions that a tag being used in very different ways is a warning sign.  (The other warning sign is when the tag isn't used alone: how many times do you see homework as the only tag?)

Comment: @Roger Neither of those indicates that it's homework.  Homework is an indication to the answerer on how they should phrase their answer--basic really means nothing to the answerer.  About as different as you can get. On the other hand, searching for "homework" isn't useful and that's probably the only view you are considering.

Comment: @Bill: The blog says "we have to discourage [these tags] ... make sure it doesn’t come to DOMINATE the top (n) tags list"; [homework] is the only such tag left on the [first page of tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags).  What other tags give instructions to answerers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of this seems to be a confusion between C and Java....

```
if(a[i]=='\0' || b[j]=='\0')
        return 0;
```

C has a null terminator for strings, Java does not.  Instead to check for the end of a Java array you will need to use the .length attribute... something like:

```
   if(i >= a.length || j >= b.length)
```

Edit based on comment.

Really, you should ask a separate question on this... but here is a stab at how it works.  First off you are using recursion, which, yes, is a tricky concept.  Wikipedia probably can help you with the basics of recursion.

Here is the code closer to how I would write it, with comments showing you the order that things occur in:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int value;

        value = score("ACGT", "AC");
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static int score(final String gene1,
                            final String gene2)
    {
        final char[] a;
        final char[] b;
        final int    s;

        a = gene1.toCharArray();
        b = gene2.toCharArray();
        s = score(a, b, 0, 0);

        return (s);
    }

    private static int score(final char[] a,
                             final char[] b,
                             final int    idxA,
                             final int    idxB)
    {
        final int value;

        // for all calls: a.length == 4 and b.length == 2
        // first call:  idxA == 0 and idxB == 0 - false || false == false
        // second call: idxA == 1 and idxB == 1 - false || false == false
        // third call:  idxA == 2 and idxB == 2 - false || true  == true      
        if(idxA >= a.length || idxB >= b.length)
        {
            // third call: will return 0            
            value = 0;
        }
        // first call:  a[idxA] == A and b[idxB] == A - true
        // second call: a[idxB] == C and b[idxB] == C - true 
        else if(a[idxA] == b[idxB])
        {
            // this is recursion
            // first call:  1 + score(a, b, 1, 1)
            // second call: 1 + score(a, b, 2, 2)

            // after the third call the call stack starts unwinding
            // second call: 1 + 0 == 1
            // first call:  1 + 1 == 2
            value = 1 + score(a, b, idxA + 1, idxB + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            final int x;
            final int y;

            x = score(a, b, idxA + 1, idxB);
            y = score(a, b, idxB,     idxB + 1);
            value = max(x, y);
        }

        // third call:  0
        // second call: 1
        // first call:  2
        return (value);
    }

    // Can you use Math.max(int, int) instad?
    private static int max(final int x, final int y)
    {
        final int value;

        if(x < y)
        {
            value = y;
        }
        else
        {
            value = x;
        }

        return (value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok now that I have working code, I realized I got pretty lucky. I have small idea of how it works, but not a full one. I tried tracing it on paper, but it gets really messy. Whats a good way of trying to understand how this is working?

Comment: @fprime Try looking at my updated answer for some ideas on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int score(String gene1, String gene2){
    char[] a=gene1.toCharArray();//assign it directly
    char[] b=gene2.toCharArray();
    return score(a, b, 0, 0);
}

private static int score(char[] a, char[] b, int i, int j) {
    //check for end using length, java doesn't use that nullbyte-stuff for it
    //this caused the failure
    if(i==a.length || j==b.length) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a[i]==b[j]) {
        return 1+score(a, b, i+1, j+1);
    } else {
        return max(score(a, b, i+1, j), score(a, b, i, j+1));
    }
}

private static int max (int a, int b){
    if (a<b) return b;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: In general it's better to explain what's wrong, rather than just post fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] a=new char[gene1.length()];
a=gene1.toCharArray();
```

Hmm. What happens to the array that you allocated in that first line?